# If childView of ConainerView is another containerView, it throws error

Tags: ember.js

With new emberJS RC1 version, I am not able to add containerView as a childView of a parent containerView.

```
  window.App = Ember.Application.create();

  App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource("users");
  });

App.UsersView = Ember.ContainerView.extend({
    init : function(){
        this._super();
        this.pushObject(Ember.ContainerView.create({
    init: function(){
        this.pushObject(Ember.View.create({
            templateName : 'test1'
        }));
    }
}));
    }
});
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/codejack/TaWAU/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use the init function to set properties on an object. If you use 'didInsertElement' it works:

```
App.UsersView = Ember.ContainerView.extend({
    didInsertElement : function(){
        this._super();
        this.pushObject(Ember.ContainerView.create({
    didInsertElement: function(){
        this.pushObject(Ember.View.create({
            templateName : 'test1'
        }));
    }
}));
```

Comment: oh yea its working with didInsertElement...but i want to understand the part that when i am able to add childs(of containerView) in `init()` of parentView...I am not able to do same with childView's containerView...wat can be the main reason?..why this difference?..

Comment: The init()-method should be there to initialize basic object state. In your case you are using it to build a complex object graph. This seems awkward to me and can likely lead to such issues. You are starting to add a childView in a moment, where Ember might want to perform some magic. You don't know, wether Ember wants to do some  required "magic" after your init method, right?